# How to pass a list from controller post action to a view without using Json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, selectlist

I'm coding with ASP.NET Core. I have a form in a view that has several select inputs to insert orders. I want to change asp-items in select input of Products at run time, after changing select inputs of Properties of Products.
In other words, a select input populates with a new list, after selecting new value in other inputs.

I try to use ajax for bind new list to select. but I don't know how to send the output list to  ajax without json result. Is there any way to send list to view?

View's Code:

```
<form id="InsertForm">
  <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label asp-for="ProductTitleId" class="control-label"></label>
     <select asp-for="ProductTitleId" asp-items="@ViewBag.ProductTitles" class="form-control" id="txtProductTitleId" name="SearchItem">
         <option value="0" disabled selected>Select an item...</option>
     </select>
     <span asp-validation-for="ProductTitleId" class="text-danger </span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label asp-for="ProductTypeId" class="control-label"></label>
     <select asp-for="ProductTypeId" asp-items="@ViewBag.ProductTypes" class="form-control" id="txtProductTypeId" name="SearchItem">
        <option value="0" disabled selected>Select an item...</option>
     </select>
     <span asp-validation-for="ProductTypeId" class="text-danger"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label asp-for="SizeId" class="control-label"></label>
     <select asp-for="SizeId" asp-items="@ViewBag.Sizes" id="txtSizeId" class="form-control" name="SearchItem">
         <option value="0" disabled selected>Select an item...</option>
     </select>
     <span asp-validation-for="SizeId" class="text-danger"></span>
  </div>                
  <div class="form-group">
     <label asp-for="FinalProductId" class="control-label"></label>
     <select asp-for="FinalProductId" asp-items="@ViewBag.FinalProducts" class="form-control" dir="rtl" id="txtFinalProductId">
         <option value="0" disabled selected>Select an item...</option>
     </select>
     <span asp-validation-for="FinalProductId" class="text-danger"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <button type="submit" class="btn">Insert</button>
  </div>
</form>
    
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('[name = SearchItem]').change(function () {
          var _url = '@Url.Action("FindFinalProductCode", "Order")';
          $.ajax({
                url: _url,
                type: "Post",
                data: {
                        ProductTitleId: $("#txtProductTitleId option:selected").val(),
                        ProductTypeId: $("#txtProductTypeId option:selected").val(),
                        SizeId: $("#txtSizeId option:selected").val(),
                },
                success: function (data) {
                        $("#txtFinalProductId").empty();
                        $("#txtFinalProductId").append('<option value="' + "0" + '">' + "Select an item..." + '</option>');
                        $("#txtFinalProductId").items(data);  ///????
                        });
                },
                error: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                }
           });
    
         });
     });    
</script>
```

Controller's Code: OrderController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult FindFinalProductCode(FinalProductViewModel finalProductViewModel)
{
    List<FinalProduct> finalProducts = FindFinalProduct(finalProductViewModel);
    return OK(finalProducts);
}
```

ViewModel's Code: FinalProductViewModel.cs

```
public class FinalProductViewModel
{
   [Display(Name = "Title")]
   public int ProductTitleId { get; set; }
        
   [Display(Name = "Type")]
   public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
        
   [Display(Name = "Size")]
   public int SizeId { get; set; }
}
```

I don't know how to re-populate asp-items with ajax at run time.
**How to change my code to run correctly?**

Comment: So basically, you would like to repolupate all of your `dropdown value` based on any change event right? You can do that on `dropdown change event`, `onchange` you can call the `API controller` and get the value you want then bind the dropdown value again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As mentioned in my code, our idea is same. but in implementation of this idea, I have some challenges that describe in my question.

Comment: I got your concern, aren't you are looking for the a solution for loading your `dependent dropdown` based on your `parent dropdown` for instance, you would like to load `final product` based on `product id` and `size id` is it correct? Could you please share how you are loading  your initial dropdown? I mean how you are initializing dowpdown in `controller`?

Comment: In addition, could you please share what `FindFinalProduct(finalProductViewModel)` does? I mean the details?

Comment: It's a method that do some functions on its Input and return a list as output.

Comment: Could you please share the details? In addition, based the on `ProductTitleId`, `ProductTypeId` and  `SizeId` you would like to load `FinalProductId` is that correct?

Comment: No, I want to find finalProducts that have same size, same productTitle, and same productType according to input.